# (WooCommerce) Remove Sidebar only on Single-Product page

Tags: plugins, sidebar

I'm creating a theme and don't want to display the sidebar on single-product's page.

Following the recommendations of WooCommerce, I made a copy of "**templates**" folder (under woocommerce plugin) and installed on **mytheme/templates**, changing the folder's name to "**woocommerce**". On my theme's root, I created a file called **sidebar-shop.php**.

By now I have the sidebar displayed on the shop page and on the single-product page. I tried to remove `do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');` from woocommerce/single-product.php and also tried to create a conditional on **woocomerce/shop/sidebar.php**, something like:

```
if (!is_page('single-product') { 
    get_sidebar('shop'); 
}
```

but the sidebar remains.

Is there a working option to remove only the single product sidebar?

Comment: i think u need to add this line also on the single-product template file - `remove_action( 'woo_main_after', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10)`

Comment: Tried but not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional tag for single products is is_product()

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'remove_sidebar_shop');
function remove_sidebar_shop() {
if ( is_product('add-page-i.d-here') ) {
    remove_action('woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar');
    }
}
```

You may also want to change the layout on that product page to full width to remove the gap and reduce the width of the content area using a custom body class which you can also generate conditionally.

Woo Commerce conditional tags http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/

Comment: `is_product()` is just a wrapper for `is_singular('product')`. So, both works exactly the same.

Comment: You would need to add the single product page slug if ( is_product('t-shirt') ) {

Comment: And how if I want to remove it for all products? I mean, no specific ID

Comment: if ( is_product() ) {

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes..

```
function remove_sidebar_shop() {
    if ( is_singular('product') ) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar');
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'remove_sidebar_shop');
```

Comment: Abhik, the code looked promissing but not worked too. Wonder if "product" is the real ID of single-product page. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @serranegra my bad. `init` is too late to remove the action. Code corrected and should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_storefront_sidebar() {
    if ( is_product() ) {
    remove_action( 'storefront_sidebar', 'storefront_get_sidebar', 10 );
    }
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'remove_storefront_sidebar' );
```

It works with latest woocommerce 2.5.2
Also CSS needed:

```
.single-product.right-sidebar .content-area {
  float: none;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```